# Capture text after keyword and before newline

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture text after a keyword `Company :` all of the way to the end of the line. I've spent many hours on stack exchange and online regex testers trying to find the right combination.

I'm very close but my output continues to capture the new line. Regex101.com states that .*? matches any character (except newline). I'm stumped as to why it keeps capturing the newline.

Here is a snippet of the text I'm searching:

> blahblahblah\nCompany : BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC\nContact Name :
>   STEVE SMITH Fax: (000)000-0000\nContact Phone: (000)000-0000\n

Here is the code

```
sCompany = re.compile(r'(?<=Company : )(.+?)(?=Contact)')
m = re.search(sCompany,msgBody)
```

Here is my output:

> BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC\n

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you just trim the last character?

Comment: `line.split("Company :",1)[1]`

Comment: I hope by `\n` you are showing us where a newline should be. You are sure there arent 2 chars \ and n?

Comment: In showing the \n I'm copying the text from the source.Hmm. I hadn't thought that it would just be two characters and I could just use trim. print m.group(0)[:-2] did it. Thanks!

Comment: you said you want to capture text after a keyword (Company : ), so Company: should be included or you want to capture what's after Company;?

Comment: @JoeR. I mistyped. I should have said I wanted to capture all of the text after Company : and before the new line. My code with the slice on the end does that now

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
x = 'blahblahblah\nCompany : BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC\nContact Name : STEVE SMITH Fax: (000)000-0000\nContact Phone: (000)000-0000\n'
print re.findall(r'Company.*', x)
```

Output:

```
['Company : BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC']
```

I see, you have edited your OP so if you don't want the `Company:` included, you want the text after the `Company:` then you can do this:

```
fromco = re.compile('Company :(.*)')
print fromco.search(x).group(1)
```

The output:

```
BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC
```

Comment: Maybe re.findall(r'Company.*', x)[0] ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to use regex (maybe your problem or text/dataset is more complex/longer than you provide), but the problem you want to solve can be easily solved in one line:

```
newmsgBody = [x.strip() for x in msgBody.split('\n') if x.startswith('Company')][0]
print(newmsgBody)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Yes, my text is much longer. I used regex for something else recently and I thought I would try it on this problem.

Comment: The length is not a problem, the structure would be. Are all your sentences split by \n?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a 1 line (In [18]) if all your data is organized the same.

```
In [16]: string
Out[16]: 'blahblahblah\nCompany : BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC\nContact Name : STEVE SMITH Fax: (000)000-0000\nContact Phon
e: (000)000-0000\n'
In [17]: string.split('\n')
Out[17]: 
['blahblahblah',
 'Company : BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC',
 'Contact Name : STEVE SMITH Fax: (000)000-0000',
 'Contact Phone: (000)000-0000',
 '']
In [18]: string.split('\n')[1]
Out[18]: 'Company : BALDWIN LINE CONST OF MD INC'
```

Comment: Thanks. This would work also. Every file is organized the same way.